# Recaptcha for user regiter form in Keycloak4.7.0 final is not working

Tags: timeout, recaptcha, frame, keycloak, user-registration

I have integrated re-captcha for user register in Keycloack and when it is loading the recaptcha div is not showing. 
After some time it gives following timeout errors in Chrome console.

`www.gstatic.com/:1 Refused to frame 'https://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".`

`registrations?client_id=my-service&redirect_uri=http.......&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=........:1 Uncaught (in promise) Timeout
www.gstatic.com/:1 Refused to frame 'https://www.google.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".`

I found this error reported here in [https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-4584] but I am not so clear how the problem is addressed.

Is there any possible way to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

There is official manual for Recaptcha integration: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/index.html#_recaptcha

You can configure `Content-Security-Policy` in Realm's admin console by going to 
`admin` -> `Realm Settings` -> `Security Defenses`.